# pywinautoに関しまして

Tags: python

```Python
# coding: utf-8
from datetime import datetime
from pywinauto import application
app = application.Application.start("notepad.exe")

app.Notepad.Edit1.SetText(unicode(datetime.now()))
app.Notepad.MenuSelect(u"ファイル->名前を付けて保存")
dialog = app[u"名前を付けて保存"]
dialog.Edit1.SetText(u"datetime.txt")
dialog.Button1.Click()

confirm = app[u"名前を付けて保存の確認"]
if confirm.Exists():
    confirm.Button1.Click()


app.Notepad.TypeKeys("%FX")
```

以下内容のエラーが出るのですが、

```
 Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
  a[besti+bestsize] == b[bestj+bestsize]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "L:/tools/Python/pyauto/notepad.py", line 7, in <module>
    app.Notepad.MenuSelect(u"ファイル->名前を付けて保存")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\HwndWrapper.py", line 1316, in MenuSelect
    self.MenuItem(path, exact=exact).Select()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\HwndWrapper.py", line 1266, in MenuItem
    return self.Menu().GetMenuPath(path, appdata = menu_appdata, exact=exact)[-1]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\controls\menuwrapper.py", line 470, in GetMenuPath
    self.Items())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findbestmatch.py", line 139, in find_best_match
    raise MatchError(items = text_item_map.keys(), tofind = search_text)
pywinauto.findbestmatch.MatchError
```

ユニコードがおかしいのでしょうか？
当方プログラム初心者の為、解決策を見出すことができません。
ご教授いただけませんでしょうか？
Pythonは2.79 pywinautoは0.41を使用しております。
お手数ですがよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: pywinautoはきっとASCIIのみの環境でしかテストされていないのでしょう。WindowsのコントロールのIDに日本語が入っているわけで、その文字列がUTF8以外の可能性があると思います。まさか今時SJISでもないとは思いますが。findbestmatch.pyを編集してfind_best_match()の引数のsearch_textとitemsの中身を`print repr()でプリントすればどんな文字列（バイト列）を比較しようとしているのかわかるでしょう。解決策はそれを確認してから考えましょう。

Answer (score 2):

`pywinauto/controls/menuwrapper.py`というファイルには、`win32gui.GetMenuItemInfo`が使われているのですが、その関数はユニコードを対応しないと思います。

より[古いバージョンのpywinautoのコード](http://pywinauto.googlecode.com/hg-history/d46c607b2a4850b3c2395263e50a90f89da20374/pywinauto/controls/menuwrapper.py)をチェックすると、`pywinauto/win32functions.py`の`GetMenuItemInfo`が使われています。`win32functions`というファイルには、`GetMenuItemInfo`は`ctypes.windll.user32.GetMenuItemInfoW`というユニコードを対応する関数に送信しています。

`MenuItem`というクラスの`_read_item`と`Text`を古いコードに置き換えると、動くようになるみたいです：

```
# coding: utf-8
import ctypes
from datetime import datetime
from pywinauto import application
from pywinauto.controls.menuwrapper import MenuItem, win32structures, win32functions, win32defines


def _read_item(self):
    """Read the menu item info

    See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/winui/winui/windowsuserinterface/resources/menus/menureference/menufunctions/getmenuiteminfo.asp
    for more information."""
    menu_info  = win32structures.MENUITEMINFOW()
    menu_info.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof (menu_info)
    menu_info.fMask = \
        win32defines.MIIM_CHECKMARKS | \
        win32defines.MIIM_ID | \
        win32defines.MIIM_STATE | \
        win32defines.MIIM_SUBMENU | \
        win32defines.MIIM_TYPE #| \
        #MIIM_FTYPE #| \
        #MIIM_STRING
        #MIIM_DATA | \

    ret = win32functions.GetMenuItemInfo (
        self.menu,
        self.index,
        True,
        ctypes.byref(menu_info))

    if not ret:
        raise ctypes.WinError()

    return menu_info

def Text(self):
    "Return the state of this menu item"

    info = self._read_item()
    # if there is text
    if info.cch:
        # allocate a buffer
        buffer_size = info.cch+1
        text = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(buffer_size)

        # update the structure and get the text info
        info.dwTypeData = ctypes.addressof(text)
        info.cch = buffer_size

        win32functions.GetMenuItemInfo (
            self.menu,
            self.index,
            True,
            ctypes.byref(info))

        text = text.value
    else:
        text = ''

    return text
MenuItem._read_item = _read_item
MenuItem.Text = Text


app = application.Application.start("notepad.exe")

app.Notepad.Edit1.SetText(unicode(datetime.now()))
app.Notepad.MenuSelect(u"ファイル->名前を付けて保存")
dialog = app[u"名前を付けて保存"]
dialog.Edit1.SetText(u"datetime.txt")
dialog.Button1.Click()

confirm = app[u"名前を付けて保存の確認"]
if confirm.Exists():
    confirm.Button1.Click()


app.Notepad.TypeKeys("%FX")
```

なので、`pywinauto`というモジュール内のユニコードバグみたいです。